# Google Chrome v.30 : CSS overflow attribute on input elements cause other inputs to jump on focus state

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, input, overflow

**This bug seems to only appear on Chrome version 30.0 +**

When I focus on an input element with `overflow: hidden`, it cause other input elements to jump. Any idea why this happen?

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8JHd6/3/

Comment: I can confirm that Chrome 29 on Linux does not do anything weird, but Chrome 30 on Win7 does.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I didn't see anything about this in the Google Chrome bug tracker.

Comment: Since Chrome 30 was only released on Oct. 3, yesterday as of this comment, it's likely you're one of the first people to spot this. You should probably file a bug ticket.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just opened a bug ticket in the Chrome bug tracker, I hope I'll get some answers there. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=304210&thanks=304210&ts=1380905932

Comment: I just found out that `overflow: auto` and `overflow: scroll` are even worse. http://jsfiddle.net/8JHd6/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the official review : https://codereview.chromium.org/26454004

> r155341 (https://codereview.chromium.org/21414002) made us follow the
>   CSS spec for the alignment of overflow: hidden; in combination with
>   display: inline-block;. Unfortunately, that had the side-effect of
>   changing the baselines for  elements, because we internally
>   implement them as inline-blocks. This CL overrides the baseline
>   computation so that they align the same way with or without overflow.
>
> (NOTE: Any websites that were broken by this can fix it by just
>   removing overflow: hidden, because it has no effect on 
>   elements)

Comment: This is now fixed with Canary Version 32.0.1666.0 on Mac OS X 10.8.5

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this behavior is a bug in the new version of Chrome.

Here's the bug ticket, I hope it will be fixed soon.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=304210&thanks=304210&ts=1380905932

Feel free to add any information about this bug.